# React native: crash while requesting permissions

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation

I'm following this tutorial to get user's location on iOS React Native app:
https://hackernoon.com/react-native-basics-geolocation-adf3c0d10112

Using this code to get current location:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  console.log(position); // TBD
  this.setState({ location: true });
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error); // Handle this
  this.setState({ location: false });
}, {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 20000,
  maximumAge: 1000,
});
```

But the app crashes at this file:

PermissionsAndroid.js:

```
  const shouldShowRationale = await NativeModules.PermissionsAndroid.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
```

with error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale of undefined at PermissionsAndroid.Request$

But I'm not even running on Android - I'm running iOS.

Could this be a RN bug or how I'm using it?

Comment: Could you tell me your RN 's version?

Comment: Version is 0.57.5

Answer (score 0):

Just had to request permissions first:

```
await navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization();
```